# How to detect if the elements are loaded dynamically.

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check if the elements that are loaded dynamically have complete loaded.

I want the user to click the button -> load elements -> check if the elements are loaded.

I have

```
<button id='click'>click</button>


//create and append div..
$('#click').click(function(){

   var div= $('<div>').attr('id','testDiv').addClass('div');

   $('body').append(div);

})


//detect when the div is loaded...
$('#testDiv').load(function(){
    console.log('load test div')

})
```

How do I get 'load test div' show in the console.... thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) does what you think it does.

Comment: Load is for ajax calls. Why do you want to know that? After append it is in dom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements aren't loaded, when you add them to the dom they are there. So right after `$('body').append(div);` the div is in the dom.